# systemd: how to enable a service automatically from the first boot?

Tags: systemd

I am using systemd to handle some tasks and I have a service file which works fine once enabled with **systemctl**.

Now, I would like to enable it automatically from the first boot.

I know that putting a replacement file into `/etc/systemd/system/` replaces the behavior of the file with the same name into `/lib/systemd/system/`.

There is a way to enable a service file automatically just to putting it in some directory ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **IMPORTANT NOTE:** The following works for me under Ubuntu. It should work as is under Debian. RPM based distros *prevent* the auto-start by default, but it may still get you closer to your goal.

In most cases, you want to *install* it in the `multi-user.target` using the install section as follow:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This means the `your-package.postinst` script will automatically start the daemon for you.

Note that if you have your own `your-package.postinst` script, you have to make sure to include the Debian helper as in:

```
#!/bin/sh

#DEBHELPER#

...your own script here...
```

Without the `#DEBHELPER#` pattern, the packager will not add the default code and as a result your daemon won't get enabled and started automatically. The code added there will enable and start the service:

```
systemctl enable <service-name>
systemctl start <service-name>
```

unless the service is `static` (does not have an `[Install]` section as shown above.) A static service requires a special command line to be enabled and that's not available by default:

```
systemctl add-wants multi-user.target <service-name>
```

As we can see, the command includes `multi-user.target` which the default `#DEBHELPER#` (systemd, really) has no clue about unless you have an `[Install]` section.

---

**Update:** In newer versions, the systemd extension is now part of the installation mechanism and the following is not required anymore. For Ubuntu, I think that started with 22.04, maybe 21.10.

The package must also be built with the `systemd` extension. This means having the following in your `debian/rules` file:

```
%:
    dh $@ --with systemd --parallel
```

That should get you set.

---

Just in case, if you wanted to **not** start the newly installed service, you can actually prevent such by adding the following:

```
override_dh_installsystemd:
    dh_installsystemd --no-start --no-disable
```

Mix and match as required by your system.

Answer (score 5):

`sudo systemctl enable <service-name>` will enable service at boot time.

http://www.dynacont.net/documentation/linux/Useful_SystemD_commands/ has a list of useful commands. And there's always `man systemctl` and `man systemd`.

Comment: Note that you need at least the statement `WantedBy=multi-user.target` under `[Install]` in the unit file for it to start on boot *in addition* to enabling it via systemctl, otherwise the enable command won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [systems.preset](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) for default enabled units.

Systems.preset allows to configure set of units to be enabled/disabled

`vendor preset` in `systemctl status unit` refers to this.

For more info how use this refer linked man page